# Choosing right eloquent relationship to find students registered under an event

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a `users` table

[image]

I have  an `events` table

[image]

I have an `portal_event_users` table

[image]

I am trying to  find all the users and their names registered for an event. Please advice on what eloquent relationship shall I use to access user details like below

```
public static function getstudents($event_id) {

        try {
            if ($event_id) {
                $eventobj = \App\Models\Event::find($event_id);
                if (!empty($eventobj)) {
                                        
                    $response = ['users' => $eventobj->students->users];
                    
                    return response()->json($response);
                    
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            
        }
    }
```

This is what I added in the Event model

```
class Event extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'portal_events';
    
     public function students()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(EventUser::class);
    }
   
}
```

My EventUser Model

```
class EventUser extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'portal_event_users';
    
      public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'portal_event_users','event_id','user_id')->withTimeStamps();//,'user_id','event_id');
    }
    
    public function events()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Event::class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly link events to the users using belongstomany relationship and portal_event_users pivot table

```
class Event extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'portal_events';
    
      public function users()
    {
        return 
        $this>belongsToMany(User::class,'portal_event_users','event_id','user_id')->withTimeStamps();
    }
     public function students()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(EventUser::class);
    }
   
}
```

then u can call $event->users for users associated with that event
more info refer https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

also, u don't need to create a model for pivot table if you dont need to directly update them